# marshalling/ unmarshalling in golang using a pointer

Tags: go, marshalling, unmarshalling

Can anyone explain me when to use a pointer while marshalling/unmarshalling a Json structure

Like in the example below **Created** a pointer where as **Starships** doesn't.

```
type SampleDate struct{
    Starships []string  `json:"starships"`
    Created   *time.Time `json:"created"`
}
```

Comment: Use a pointer to distinguish between no value and the zero value in the JSON document.

Comment: can you explain further please?

Comment: See the explanation at https://stackoverflow.com/a/56324510/5728991

Comment: `Starships` is also a pointer: slices in Go are pointers themselves

Comment: And you can use `json:"created,omitempty"` for omiiting it when converting the object to JSON.